# VUE3.JS - Modal in a loop

Tags: vuejs3

I have a GET request in my home.vue component.
This query allows me to get an array of objects.
To display all the objects, I do a v-for loop and everything works fine.

```
<div class="commentaires" v-for="(com, index) of coms" :key="index">
```

My concern is that I want to display an image by clicking on it (coms[index].imageUrl), in a modal (popup).
The modal is displayed fine but not with the correct image, i.e. the modal displays the last image obtained in the loop, which is not correct.

Here is the full code of my home.vue component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="commentaires" v-for="(com, index) of coms" :key="index">
        <modale :imageUrl="com.imageUrl_$this.index" :revele="revele" :toggleModale="toggleModale"></modale>
        <img class="photo" :src=""" alt="image du commentaire" @click="toggleModale">
      </div>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
//import axios from "axios";
import axios from "axios";
import Modale from "./Modale";

export default {
  name: 'HoMe',
  data() {
    return {
      coms: [],
      revele: false
      }
    },
  components: {
    modale: Modale
  },
  methods: {
    toggleModale: function () {
      this.revele = !this.revele;
    },
</script>
```

Here is my modale.vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="bloc-modale" v-if="revele">
        <div class="overlay" @click="toggleModale"></div>
        <div class="modale card">
            <div v-on:click="toggleModale" class="btn-modale btn btn-danger">X</div>     
            <img :src=""" alt="image du commentaire" id="modal">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Modale",
    props: ["revele", "toggleModale", "imageUrl"],
};
</script>
```

I've been working on it for 1 week but I can't, so thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your v-for loop you're binding the same `revele` and `toggleModale` to every modal.  When there is only one `revele` then any time it's `true`, all modals will be displayed.  It's therefore likely you're actually opening all modals and simply seeing the last one in the stack.  You should modify `coms` so that each item has it's own `revele`, e.g.:

```js
coms = [
  {
    imageUrl: 'asdf',
    revele: false
  },
  {
    imageUrl: 'zxcv',
    revele: false
  },
  {
    imageUrl: 'ghjk',
    revele: false
  }
];
```

then inside your v-for:

```html
<modale
    :image-url="com.imageUrl"
    :revele="com.revele"
    @toggle-modale="com.revele = false"
></modale>
<img class="photo" :src=""" alt="image du commentaire" @click="com.revele = true">
```

passing the same function as a prop to each modal to control the value of `revele` is also a bad idea.  Anytime a prop value needs to be modified in a child component, the child should emit an event telling the parent to modify the value. Notice in my code snippet above I replaced the prop with an event handler that turns the `revele` value specific to that modal to false.  Inside each modal you should fire that event:

modale.vue

```html
<div class="btn-modale btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('toggle-modale')">
    X
</div>
```

This way you don't need any function at all to control the display of the modals.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'll try your proposition and I come back to you

Comment: It's very good. Your code is better than mine.
Thanks a lot